# How to place Kivy app to specific location on screen

Tags: kivy

I want to place app on specific location on screen. Let say I would like to place it at bottom right corner.

I found `Config.set('graphics', 'position', 'custom')` and then follows `Config.set('graphics', 'left', <int>)` and `Config.set('graphics', 'top', <int>)`. Since there is no `bottom` and `right` key I need find a way how to get screen size (physical device). I did not found anything in their documentation related to my issue.

I would like to make it platform independent (Win/Linux/Mac).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there is no easy way to do what you want. I have struggled with a similar issue myself. Below is an example code that you can use as a starting point:

```
import subprocess
import platform

def getDisplaySize():
    p = platform.platform()
    if p.startswith('Linux'):
        cp = subprocess.run('xdpyinfo', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                            universal_newlines=True)
        if cp.returncode == 0:
            lines = cp.stdout.split('\n')
            for line in lines:
                line = line.strip()
                if line.startswith('dimensions:'):
                    size = line.split()[1]
                    tokens = size.split('x')
                    try:
                        width = int(tokens[0])
                        height = int(tokens[1])
                        return (width, height)
                    except:
                        continue
    elif p.startswith('Windows'):
        cp = subprocess.run(['wmic', 'desktopmonitor', 'get',  'ScreenHeight,ScreenWidth'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                        universal_newlines=True)
        if cp.returncode == 0:
            lines = cp.stdout.split('\n')
            for line in lines:
                tokens = line.split()
                try:
                    width = int(tokens[0])
                    height = int(tokens[1])
                    return (width, height)
                except:
                    continue

        # try another method
        cp = subprocess.run(['wmic', 'path', 'Win32_VideoController', 'get', 'CurrentHorizontalResolution,CurrentVerticalResolution'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
                            universal_newlines=True)
        if cp.returncode == 0:
            lines = cp.stdout.split('\n')
            for line in lines:
                tokens = line.split()
                try:
                    width = int(tokens[0])
                    height = int(tokens[1])
                    return (width, height)
                except:
                    continue
    # failed to get display size
    return (0,0)

dispSize = getDisplaySize()

if dispSize[0] !=0 and dispSize[1] != 0:
    from kivy.config import Config
    w = int(Config.get('graphics', 'width'))
    h = int(Config.get('graphics', 'height'))
    print('Display Size:', dispSize)
    print('App Width, Height:', w, h)
    Config.set('graphics', 'position', 'custom')
    Config.set('graphics', 'left', dispSize[0] - w)
    Config.set('graphics', 'top', dispSize[1] - h)

# do not import any kivy modules (other than Config) before this point
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text='Abba')

TestApp().run()
```

Shortcomings of the above code:

1. Does not handle Mac (I have no Macs to experiment with).
2. Does not handle scaled displays. Both Windows and Linux allow you to set a scale factor for the display. If the scale factor is 1.0, the above code should work.
3. Does not handle cases where multiple displays are available.
4. Only tested on Windows 10, and Ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: I thought about something similar, but instead of using subprocess module I planned to use package from pypi but I haven't did any search yet.

Comment: If you find something that works, please post it as an answer to your own question. I have seen this same question many times.

Comment: sure I will do :)